# Passing parameters to object or inherit object's function?

Tags: javascript, function, object, inheritance, prototype

Second `console.log()` executed by `WSFunctions[this.name]();` will print `undentified`. I was wondering if I am able somehow to `inherit` `DoThisAndThat` in my `Call()` function. I didn't want to pass params in the way `WSFunctions[this.name](this.params)` as while project grows there may be more than `this.params` to pass.

```
function WS(name, params) {
    this.name = name;
    this.params = params;
}

WS.prototype.Call = function() {
    if (typeof WSFunctions[this.name] !== "function") {
        return false;
    }

    console.log(this.params);
    WSFunctions[this.name]();

    return true;
}

var WSFunctions = {
    'ScreenRightGuest': function() {
        // .. whatever ..
        return true;        
    },
    'DoThisAndThat': function() {
        console.log(this.params);
        return true;
    }
}


new WS('DoThisAndThat', { login: '123', pass: 'abc' }).Call();
```

Thanks in advance
Mike

Comment: Or maybe you have different suggestion how to build that, I'm just starting with JavaScript "classes".

Comment: This does not really have anything to do with "classes" or inheritance or prototypes, only with how `this` and calling functions work,

Comment: Yeah it's a really Strange pattern. You're building an instance of an object and refering to "static function" of that type using a "property" of this object.

Comment: The idea is that only `var WSFunctions` will be customized in future simply by adding new functions. Also, they will be called using new WS('name', <parameters_optional>). There is Call() as prototype as there will be more in future, Reload(), Copy() etc

Comment: It still seems to be weird to have `WSFunctions` as external dependency. You should either assign them to the prototype as well or pass them as argument to `WS`.

Comment: So you suggest to make `WS.prototype.ScreenRightGuest` and `WS.prototype.DoThisAndThat` **OR ** what do you mean by passing them as param to WS?

Comment: Like `new WS(WSFunctions, 'DoThisAndThat', { login: '123', pass: 'abc' })` and assign the object to a property like you did with `params`. The whole construct seems to be a bit strange to me, but I think a discussion of your application design is out of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly set what `this` should refer to in a function using [`.call` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
WSFunctions[this.name].call(this);
```

This will call `WSFunctions[this.name]` with `this` being set to what `this` refers to in the caller (in this case the instance created by `new WS(...)`).

Also have a look at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) which thoroughly explains how `this` works.

Comment: Thank you of course that did the trick, I would be delighted if you can follow me in comments in first post.